# Using Javascript ES6 import and export functionality in Codepen projects

Tags: javascript, import, babeljs, es6-modules, codepen

I am trying to use the Javascript ES6 import/export functionality in my [Codepen project](https://codepen.io/spw1016/project/editor/AmyLwb), and I thought it was supported based on some [articles](https://blog.codepen.io/projects/using-babel-codepen-project/) I read, but I am having trouble getting it to work. I have set my Codepen project to use Webpack and Babel to process my javascript file, and even tried using Chrome Canary to see if that would support ES6 (to no avail).

In my Codepen project, I wrote a basic example exporting a string variable from one file:

```
//data.js
export let firstName = 'George';
```

Then importing it into my primary javascript file to log in the console:

```
//index.js
import firstName from "./data";
console.log(FirstName);
```

Unfortunately, the Chrome console is reporting the error:

```
Uncaught VM3034 index.js:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work, if possible? I even found another example of a [Codepen project using ES6 import/export successfully](https://codepen.io/maximebj/project/editor/DvzOBD), but I'm not sure what I'm doing differently to get the error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example:

**Import**
https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/jzWjLe

```
import { getNodes } from 'https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/BrjgdY.js';

let videoHTML = getNodes(`
  <div class="widget">
    <h2>I'm a widget!</h2>
    <p>I do widgeting.</p>
  </div>
`);

document.body.appendChild(videoHTML[0]);
```

**Export**
https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/BrjgdY

```
export function getNodes(str) { 
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
}
```

Comment: it does work for me even though it throws errors in "import" pen. Some get request is failed due to this import. Does anyone have similar issue?

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me... so annoying

Comment: theres a small detail here that some people might be missing. The import statement isn't only the URL to the other pen, but it also has ".js" to call the javascript within it.

Answer (score 2):

Your project was using webpack/babel and I suspect that wasn't set up or working quite right.  This answer will not address that.  Instead, I'll describe the setup for using bare bones ES6.  Because it's 2018.

Codepen has added some documentation on how to get modules working at https://blog.codepen.io/2017/12/26/adding-typemodule-scripts-pens/

They mention that for Codepen projects you need to designate that you are using modules by adding `type="module"` to the `<script>` tag.  So in `index.html` you need to change

```
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

to

```
  <script src="scripts/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

In my working version, `data.js` looks like this:

```
function foo(str) { console.log(`foo prints ${str}`); }

let firstName = 'George'

export { foo, firstName };
```

`index.js` looks like this:

```
import {foo, firstName} from './data.js';

foo(firstName);
```

(By the way, I would have thought that `'./data'` would have worked in the `import` statement.  But no, you need `'./data.js'`)

Answer (score 0):

You've got two ways of approaching the problem. 
Either this:

```
//index.js
import firstName from "./data";
console.log(firstName);
```

with:

```
//data.js
let firstName = 'George'
export default firstName
```

In this case, you use the `default` keyword, to **default export** `firstName`. When imported, you assign, arbitrarily, the same name to it. (It could be imported with any name).

------------OR:--------------

```
// index.js
import {firstName} from "./data";
console.log(firstName);
```

with:

```
// data.js
export let firstName = 'George'
```

In this case, you import the **named export** `firstName` from the `data` module by using curly braces.

Comment: I tried both methods (Codepen updated) but neither worked. The first method you listed still gave the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" (in Chrome Canary), and the second method gave the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {". Were you able to get it working in a Codepen project? Is there something else I could be missing? Clearly it's possible since the Codepen project link I posted at the bottom was able to get it working somehow.